# Laravel-Snappy (wkhtmltopdf) is generating incorrect pdf

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, centos, wkhtmltopdf

I am using laravel 5.2 and `laravel-snappy` wrapper for `wkhtmltopdf` on a LEMP stack running on CentOS 7 (x64).

All required libraries & binaries are installed correctly; when I try to test the PDF generator like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $snappy = App::make('snappy.pdf');
    $html = '<p>Hello World :)</p><p>This is a <i>HTML</i> test <b>PDF</b>!!!</p>';
    return response($snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html), 200, [
        'Content-Type'         => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'  => 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'
    ]);
});
```

I get a PDF back, but it looks like this:

[image]

I tested this on windows (using the windows binaries) and it works perfectly fine:

[image]

---

When I tried it on Linux env, I got this error earlier:

> error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so

So, I installed these packages (as suggested [here](https://www.svennd.be/wkhtmltopdf-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxrender-so-1/)):

```
yum install libXrender fontconfig libXext
```

After this, I was not getting any error, the pdf was generating but with squares.

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out I need these packages (specifically the fonts `urw-fonts`). So,  to resolve this bug:

```
yum install libXrender fontconfig libXext urw-fonts
```

The PDF is now generating correctly.